# What are the physical implications of modelling a rider on a unicycle as a massless rod and spring attached to a point mass?

Tags: control-engineering, applied-mechanics, torque, modeling

*Foreword* This is not an industrial question; I will not profit from any answers, and I am asking because it is the subject of my final year project at university. Also apologies to the US for using British English spelling.

I am trying to design a controller for an electric unicycle, *EUC*, and am required to simulate results and analyse stability and so for this end I must also model a rider atop it and create a controller for the rider independently of the EUC.
Strictly speaking I will be designing the controllers for the rider and controller separately and independently, as this seems intuitive however I am open to discussion.
The EUC can be modeled as an elaborate inverted pendulum and the model is included below.
The control inputs of the system are $u = \tau_{motor} $, and the generalised coordinates are $q = (\theta, \phi)^T$. The diagram includes an additional control input $\tau_{rider}$ which is the torque exerted on the chassis by the rider, and is partly the subject of this question.
[image: Simple model of EUC]

My question is how best to model the rider simply. I want the rider to be able to move his centre of mass in a 2D plane instead of a 1D curve, visually such an example can be seen here [[Variation of centre of mass for a uncicyle rider](https://newatlas.com/urban-transport/inmotion-v13-challenger-87-mph-electric-unicycle/)] where the rider has chosen to keep his centre of gravity closer to the ground by tilting his torso and by choosing to sit down.
I believe this can best be done by modelling the rider as a uniform mass less rod and spring system attaching to a point mass at the end and originating from the foot pedal; where the rider can exert force upon the spring to compress it and torque upon the pedal to tilt the mass less rod that models the body, a similar diagram for such a model is included at the bottom of the question to help visualisation.

*Questions 1 and 2 have been moved to the bottom since they have been answered by Chat GPT. They are still included because it shows my thought process. I appreciate your responses much more then any artificial intelligence.*

3. Finally, according to newtons third law "every action must have an equal and opposite reaction". Applying this to the rider, would the reactionary force of the riders torque about the pivot of the pedal be felt between the chassis and the wheel (i.e. the rider creating clockwise momentum will result in anticlockwise momentum at the wheel)?
4. I also struggle to understand how in this simplistic model the rider would ever be able to change the value of $\psi$, since if the above point is true then the torque of the rider is only ever having effect on the angle of the chassis and the wheel.

Some physical insights to the system would be much appreciated, and I understand that this is a very open ended question and am happy to have a discussion.

**Here is the proposed rider and unicycle system:** [[EUC+Rider Simple System]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcedW.png)

*Tags* modeling, applied-mechanics, control-engineering, torque.
If these are not good tags let me know.

*Questions 1 and 2:*

1. It doesn't seem physically sensible for their to be friction between the rod and the pedal since in reality the rider and the EUC are not physically attached - Is this a fair assumption?
2. Thinking about the problem realistically (but still simplistically) the rider can exert force in two positions (not including the force exerted to compress the spring) - a force from his feet to the pedal in order to tilt the unicycle (angle $\theta$), and a torque from his torso to tilt his body (angle $\psi$ in rider + EUC diagram).
   Applying this to the model would mean that there would should be another control input to the rider, namely a force acting at the point of mass perpendicular to the rod.
   Although this seems sensible, I grapple with the reality that the torque exerted at the centre of mass and the torque exerted at the feet will become additive at the point of pivot and therefore only one should really be included in the interests of simplicity. Is this a fair conclusion?

Comment: So try various models: each with and without mass. Then you can decide which model gives the “best” or most useful results.

Comment: Real rider can shift weight in any direction, not just up and down. Also, I am not sure if point mass will be sufficient as rotation inertia of standing human might not be negligible.

Comment: @SolarMike I intend to, but I would find it difficult to be able to justifyably say which is better from the just the simulation of the models as I have little experience with unicycles and I think my intuition is quite off as well.

Comment: That’s one reason it is your project…

Comment: @TomášLétal
That is the reason for including the torque, this allows the rider to shift the weight radially clockwise/anticlockwise or up and down - making the rider able to shift his weight in any direction of the 2D plane.

Comment: @MatthewEdizBeadman Which "2D plane" are you referring to?

Comment: @TomášLétal The 2D plane is the entire plane. If you look at the diagram labelled "[EUC+Rider Simple System]" then the rider has an angle of phi, and the torque is used to change this angle (and the force is used to change the distance from the foot pedal to the centre of mass of the rider)

Comment: @MatthewEdizBeadman But which plane? Is it vertical plane or horizontal plane (perpendicular or paralel to main motion)?

Comment: @TomášLétal Sorry it's parallel to the plane of motion, the model is 2D and only consists of the plane diagramed. I will be adding quite abit to this post tommorow as I've had some revelations on modelling the rider. Just abit too tired to post it now. To clarify the torque will act out of the plane and impact the angle of phi that is within the plane